# Use the change of variables to determine the density for a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, change-of-variable

Knowing that the density of a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ is:

$f_{U}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & x\in [0,1]\\ 
0 & x\notin[0,1]
\end{matrix}\right.$

How to determine the density of a uniformly distributed random variable on $[a,b]$ using change of variable?

Comment: Hint: If $U$ is a random variable on $[0, 1]$, then what distribution does $(b-a)U+a$ have?

Comment: I know how to do this by what you said, but does is use the change of variable? Uniform dist is pretty simple so you know the pdf is 1/(b-a) and make a random variable Y=(b-a)X+a and get this pdf. But what if you don't know the pdf? I know this problem itself is somehow weird

Comment: I understood. When constructing Y=(b-a)X+a, we consider it as a scaling and shifting of X, so Y is still a uniformly distributed RV and its domian is therefore [a,b], right?

Comment: You know the density of $U$, so you can use change of variables on $f_U$ to get the density of $(b-a)U +a$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the described variable by x. Construct new variable y as $y = (b-a)x+a$

For any value z, The cumulative density function $F(y \leq z) = F(x \leq \frac{z-a}{b-a}) = \begin{cases}
0,  \, z< a\\
(z-a)/(b-a), \, z \in [a,b]\\
1, \, z > b
\end{cases} $

Take the derivative of cdf with respect to z, the pdf $f(y=z) = \begin{cases}
1/(b-a), z \in [a,b]\\
0, otherwise
\end{cases}$